# How to use dynamic_cast with an array of pointers to a subclass

Tags: c++, arrays, c++builder, dynamic-cast, c++builder-5

I have an array of pointers to object class e_t :

```
class e_t {...};
```

I wrote a template class :

```
template <class E = e_t>
class cursor_t 

     { cursor_t(e_t ** &_source, size_t _total);

       e_t ** &Source;
       size_t  Total;

       E **First();
       E **Last();
       E **Skip(E **, short);
     };
```

For every function, I will `for(_x to this->_total`) `this->Source` and stop at the first, last or skipped `dynamic_cast<E *>(*(this->Source + _x))`... Works fine and it correctly stop...

The problem comes as returning the result ! Why can't I use `e_t **` as `E **` (knowing `E` is always descending from `e_t`) ?

`return dynamic_cast<E **>(this->Source + _x);` always fails at compile time...

I am Using cbuilder 5

Comment: Please show a complete [mre]. However, I think it is very unlikely that you really want double pointers here. `e_t **` is a pointer to a `e_t*` and `E **` is a pointer to a `E*`. A `e_t*` is a completely unrelated object to a `E*` and trying to use one as the other would be an aliasing violation.

Comment: "_I have an array of pointers to object class e_t :_": If you want to iterate over an array of pointers, then all of these double pointers ought to be single pointers.

Comment: int _result(0);

Comment: I simply would like to transtype to an array of B * (inherited from A) an array of A * (array of pointers to A).... but this for only a found index of B * in the array...

Comment: You have too many pointers for that, e.g. `e_t ** &Source` is three indirections (two pointers plus one reference). But referencing an element of your array should have only two indirections because the element itself has one indirection, and only one is added in order to reference that element. Your other pointers also have this problem or should be references.

Comment: Also, you don't need to write this yourself. You can use `std::transform` with a lambda that `dynamic_cast`s each element.

Comment: `**&` gives me a headache. So does `**`.

Comment: yes... ** & is a headache... Sometimes aspirin makes the world go round... What if I need a pointer to an array of a pointer to be modified...? ** & !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have over-complicated your design with too many pointer indirections.  You have an array of pointers, you should simplify your interface by having the methods return individual elements of the array, as the caller shouldn't need direct access to the array itself, eg:

```cpp
template <class E = e_t>
class cursor_t 
{
    e_t ** Source;
    size_t Total, Current;

public:
    cursor_t(e_t ** _source, size_t _total);

    E* First();
    E* Last();
    E* Previous();
    E* Next();
    E* Skip(short count);
};

template <class E>
cursor_t<E>::cursor_t(e_t ** _source, size_t _total) :
    Source(_source),
    Total(_total),
    Current(-1)
{
}

template <class E>
E* cursor_t<E>::First()
{
    for(size_t x = 0; x < Total; ++x) {
        E *e = dynamic_cast<E*>(Source[x]);
        if (e) { Current = x; return e; }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template <class E>
E* cursor_t<E>::Last()
{
    for(size_t x = Total; x-- > 0; )
    {
        E *e = dynamic_cast<E*>(Source[x]);
        if (e) { Current = x; return e; }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template <class E>
E* cursor_t<E>::Previous()
{
    if (Current < Total)
    {
        for (size_t x = Current; x-- > 0; )
        {
            E *e = dynamic_cast<E*>(Source[x]);
            if (e) { Current = x; return e; }
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template <class E>
E* cursor_t<E>::Next()
{
    for (size_t x = Current + 1; x < Total; ++x)
    {
        E *e = dynamic_cast<E*>(Source[x]);
        if (e) { Current = x; return e; }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template <class E>
E* cursor_t<E>::Skip(short count)
{
    E *e;
    if (count > 0) {
        while ((e = Next()) != nullptr && --count >= 0);
    }
    else if (count < 0) {
        while ((e = Previous()) != nullptr && ++count <= 0);
    }
    else if (Current < Total) {
        e = static_cast<E*>(Source[Current]);
    } else {
        e = nullptr;
    }
    return e;
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
template <class E = e_t>
class cursor_t 
{
    e_t **Source, **End, **Current;

public:
    cursor_t(e_t ** _source, size_t _total);

    E* First();
    E* Last();
    E* Previous();
    E* Next();
    E* Skip(short count);
};

template <class E>
cursor_t<E>::cursor_t(e_t ** _source, size_t _total) :
    Source(_source),
    End(_source + _total),
    Current(nullptr)
{
}

template <class E>
E* cursor_t<E>::First()
{
    for(e_t *t = Source; t < End; ++t) {
        E *e = dynamic_cast<E*>(t);
        if (e) { Current = t; return e; }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template <class E>
E* cursor_t<E>::Last()
{
    for(e_t *t = End; t > Source; )
    {
        E *e = dynamic_cast<E*>(--t);
        if (e) { Current = t; return e; }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template <class E>
E* cursor_t<E>::Previous()
{
    if (Current)
    {
        for (e_t *t = Current; t > Source; )
        {
            E *e = dynamic_cast<E*>(--t);
            if (e) { Current = t; return e; }
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template <class E>
E* cursor_t<E>::Next()
{
    if (Current) 
    {
        for (e_t *t = Current + 1; t < End; ++t)
        {
            E *e = dynamic_cast<E*>(t);
            if (e) { Current = t; return e; }
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template <class E>
E* cursor_t<E>::Skip(short count)
{
    E *e;
    if (count > 0) {
        while ((e = Next()) != nullptr && --count >= 0);
    }
    else if (count < 0) {
        while ((e = Previous()) != nullptr && ++count <= 0);
    }
    else {
        e = static_cast<E*>(Current);
    }
    return e;
}
```

Comment: Standard solution you propose using loops and dynamic_cast... It's not exactly what I needed : I need your Skip function, but it has to return me the famous over starred E **, so I can quickly skip to  next or prior E *... more than looping the entire array... Certainly the entire array is not filled with only E *, so it is unsafe to use the resulting pointer of Skip (E**) and ad 1 to have the next element as it could be another pointer type... But well designed, that's ok for me...

Comment: You class should keep trace of the last returned pointer so skipping is faster... without looping the entire array...

Comment: @blueperfect what you are asking for is highly dangerous and risks *undefined behavior*. Don't do it. You need a different design.

Comment: My `Last()` loop works just fine, did you actually try it? It does not loop from `Total..0`, it actually does loop from `Total-1..0` as expected. It is written the way it is to account for `size_t` being an *unsigned* integer, thus a typical `for(size_t x = Total-1; x >= 0; --x)` loop is not safe to use due to `x` wrapping to a large number on `--x` when `x==0`.

Comment: Sorry Mister Lebeau.... Your functions works well... I didn't notice the post decrement

Comment: @blueperfect I considered using some kind of extra index or last-pointer inside the class, but that is not how your question was portrayed. You did not make your intention clear enough.

Comment: @blueperfect If you really want to make searching/skipping faster by searching only sub-sections of the array, then consider making a `span`-like interface to the array and then slice one span into a smaller span when needed, and then search only the spans you are interested in.

Comment: Intentions are to browse an array of e_t **, where some pointers are E *... But with a Fetch or Skip function efficient enough to quickly go to next or prior E * element... So these functions will take the last resulting pointer to their call (so E**) and browse the array then...

Comment: @blueperfect <sigh> fine. I have updated my answer.

Comment: ... and that exactly what I implemented....

Answer (score -3):

Thanks all folks !

I found...

I should use dynamic_cast for 1 pointer of the array, but I will use reinterpret_cast for the whole array...

Comment: "_but I will use reinterpret_cast for the whole array._": That's going to cause undefined behavior.

Comment: *...I will use reinterpret_cast for the whole array...*  Footgun loaded!  Footgun ready! 
 Footgun aimed!  Footgun fired!

Comment: There are a few, very specialised, situations where `reinterpret_cast` is an appropriate and necessary solution to a problem.   But your question does not describe one of those.   So you're opening the door for undefined behaviour, in a way that will cause blatant bugs (e.g. program crashes) or subtle bugs (e.g. data poisoning) in subsequent code.   The root cause of those bugs will be the `reinterpret_cast` but the symptoms will be in other code - so such bugs will often be difficult to track down in future.

Comment: It will be unsafe to use reinterpret_cast and add +1 or -1 on the resulting casted pointer... but if I only use the resulting pointer...then it is safe...